# Splunk Dashboard Based on the Content of the Log file

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation

My log file "app.log" contains 20-30 lines of data, example..

```
Total records 100. Successful batch size: 30. (Followed by some data here....)
Total records 100. Successful batch size: 40. (Followed by some data here....)
Total records 100. Successful batch size: 30. (Followed by some data here....)
```

I want to create a dashboard to display Total records (100) and display the sum of successful batch sizes (30+40+30) and if sum is equal to Total records need to display a green tick mark.

I am new to Splunk and I have tried to display the log data and stuck from there, can someone help me how to read and calculate? I tried with few docs in google but no luck, Thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have created 2 fields for getting total records and batch sizes numbers...!

Comment: I meant what SPL have you tried?

Comment: Have a look at | rex  if you need to extract the numbers out from the message. Then look at | stats and | eval to aggregate, visualise and compare.